# Recovering a bookmark folder

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, file-recovery

I cannot find an important folder from the chrome bookmarks. I did not make a backup.

- I already re-installed windows and chrome.
- I went from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8

**Is it possible for me now to recover that bookmark folder**? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't use the synchronize option in Chrome, they are gone after removing the program.

If the bookmarks are really important, you could hire a forensics data-recovery company or use data recovery software such as Recuva or R-Studio. In a lot of cases they can retrieve data even after it has been removed. This is because although the partitiontable was overwritten with reinstallation, the actual data isn't.

So if you might going to do that you should turn of your computer now, DONT turn it on and/or do any interactions with the harddisks. It might insert data on your drive and that could overwrite the sectors where your bookmarks were located.

Answer (score 1):

If you uninstalled Chrome before installing Windows 8, you may be out of luck (except for the options mentioned by xatr0z). If you did not uninstall Chrome itself, then Windows 8 should have backed up its data, which is kept in:

```
C:\Windows.old\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

The Bookmarks file in that directory can then be copied to:

```
C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

(This will overwrite any new bookmarks made since installing Windows 8. If it doesn't work, try copying the files beginning with "History" too, but make a backup of the files you're overwriting first.)